# How to locate 'aria-owns' attribute in Playwright using GetByRole

Tags: playwright

Here is a simplified version of the element I am trying to locate:

`<span  aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="My_listbox"> <more stuff> </span>`

I see from the Playwright documentation that the GetByRole methode allows "locating elements by their ARIA role, **ARIA attributes** and accessible name".

My question is: is the aria-owns a valid attribute to try to locate on? All I could find were examples for 'state' attributes such as checked, disabled, expanded, etc.

Is there a way to do something like:

`await _page.GetByRole(AriaRole.Listbox, new FrameGetByRoleOptions { Name = "My_listbox" }).ClickAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);`

I tried using a similar syntax as for the state attributes, but there doesn't seem to have any options for the aria-owns attribute. I am able to locate the element otherwise using other methods, but I am trying to shift to the aria roles as much as possible as it seems to be the best practice

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`await page.getByRole('listbox', { name: 'YourAccesibleName' }).click();`

Otherwise there is also an [extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright) for Playwright. It lets you pick a recommended locator directly in your website.